# ArgParse ERROR. but working in Test.py file

Tags: python, oop, sqlalchemy, argparse, traceback

My test.py file in `create_assessment` (and all the `CRUD` operations) are working, e.g. populating the `database` that I have created. However, the `ArgParse` command line, made to interact with the database, is failing in `create_assessment` because of the `category` area. `Assessment`-`Category` share a **many-to-many relationship**.

I believe the issue is due to the parser's `category` line (as shown in the `TracebackError`, but I haven't been able to figure this conundrum. The `categories` do exist in the `db`, the parser is not recognizing the categories, but recognizing them in the test.py file. It could be that `args = parser.parse_args()` isn't parsing correctly.

ERROR:

```
(venv)acks-MacBook-Pro:notssdb ack$ notssdb-cmd create_assessment 'Learning new things' 'this' dancinglady 'movie' ['Bats', 'Development', 'Swinging at nothing']
usage: API_ArgParse [-h]
                    {create_user,retrieve_user,update_user,update_user_lastname,delete_user,create_assessment,retrieve_assessment,update_assessment,delete_assessment,create_video,retrieve_video,update_video,update_video_url,delete_video,create_category,retrieve_category,update_category,delete_category,create_element,retrieve_element,update_element,delete_element,create_assessment_results,retrieve_assessment_results,delete_assessment_results,create_category_rating,retrieve_category_rating,update_category_rating,delete_category_rating,create_element_rating,retrieve_element_rating,update_element_rating,delete_element_rating,create_comment,retrieve_comment,update_comment,delete_comment}
                    ...
API_ArgParse: error: unrecognized arguments: Development, Swinging at nothing]
```

## ADDED the parser = config.

Code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='API_ArgParse', description='Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) Interface Commands for NOTSSdb')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', title='subcommands', description='type subcommand name with -h for more details : e.g. notssdb-cmd create_user -h', help='additional help')
api = ConvenienceAPI() 

# Create command for 'assessment'  
create_parser = subparsers.add_parser('create_assessment', help='create an assessment')
create_parser.add_argument('name', type=str, help='name of the assessment')
create_parser.add_argument('text', type=str, help='assessment text')
create_parser.add_argument('username', type=str, help='name of user')
create_parser.add_argument('videoname', type=str, help='name of video')
create_parser.add_argument('category_names', type=str, help='list all category names')#THIS LINE

# Parse the arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

api = ConvenienceAPI()
api_method = getattr(api, args.cmd)
arg_dict = vars(args)
del arg_dict['cmd']
api_method(**arg_dict)
```

Create_assessment method with category retrieval (convenience.py - inherits base):

```
class ConvenienceAPI(BaseAPI):          

    def create_assessment(self, name, text, username, videoname, category_names):
        user = self.retrieve_user(username)
        video = self.retrieve_video(videoname) 
        cat_objects = [self.retrieve_category(category_name) for category_name in category_names]
        return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_assessment(name, text, user, video, cat_objects)
```

Retrieve method for category (base.py):

```
def retrieve_category(self, something_unique):
    if isinstance(something_unique, int):
        return self.session.query(Category).\
        filter(Category.category_id == something_unique).all() # multiple categories
    elif isinstance(something_unique, basestring):
        print(something_unique) # added 
        return self.session.query(Category).\
        filter(Category.category_name == something_unique).one()
```

Working test.py file example:

```
api.create_assessment('How to be a leader', 'better decisions', 'wizard', 'good leadership', ['Leadership', 'Decision-Making', 'Teamwork and Communication', 'Situation Awareness'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the stuff in brackets.  The comandline processor in the shell does not recognize them.  Look at the `sys.avgv` that the parse works with.

With a simple script that just echos the `argv`, your line produces:

```
['echoargv.py', 'create_assessment', 'Learning new things', 'this',
   'dancinglady', 'movie', '[Bats,', 'Development,', 'Swinging at nothing]']
```

Notice the 2 strings in the error message:

```
'Development,'
'Swinging at nothing]'
```

The positional 'category_names' gets `'[Bats,'`, but there's no place to put the other strings.

Putting extra quotes around the brackets, `"['Bats', 'Development', 'Swinging at nothing']"`, would solve this, but assign that whole thing to 'category_names'.  You'd then have to strip and parse it.

Another option is to give 'category_names' a `nargs='+'` parameter and enter

```
notssdb-cmd create_assessment 'Learning new things' 'this' dancinglady 'movie' 'Bats', 'Development', 'Swinging at nothing'
```

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj for the clear explanation. The `nargs='+'` is exactly what  I chose to do. Much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Python list syntax in `bash` to pass a list. Your program is being passed the following string arguments:

- `Learning new things`
- `this`
- `dancinglady`
- `movie`
- `[Bats,`
- `Development,`
- `Swinging at nothing]`

If you want multiple values for `category_names`, you need the following argument, defined *last*.

```
create_parser.add_argument('category_names',
                           dest='cmd',  # since you are trying to access args.cmd later
                           nargs='+',   # need at least one, use * if not required
                           help='list all category names')
```

then call your program with

```
$ notssdb-cmd create_assessment 'Learning new things' 'this' dancinglady \
    'movie' 'Bats' 'Development' 'Swinging at nothing'
```

The first 5 arguments are assigned to the first 5 defined parameters. All remaining arguments are assigned as a list to the final parameter since it is defined with `nargs='+'`.

Comment: Figured it out! I was adding commas ... oh boy. Thank you so much! The nargs= '+' was what I needed along with no brackets in the actual call